# Controlling the flow of the debugger

Tags: java, debugging

Is there any way to control the flow of the debugger of the Eclipse. I mean when I debugged the following code snippet. (It is labelled in the code snipped below) The debugger goes to 1, 2 and 3. However, I would like to see the value of timeSeries variable before it goes to 3.

```
      if( !(ANOsEmpty && CNFsEmpty) )
       {
1 ->    List< TagesfahrplanVO > timeSeries = getTimeSeries( aEvent );
2 ->    timeSeries = clearList( timeSeries, aEvent );
       }

3 ->   if( !CNFsEmpty )
      {
       . 
       .
  The rest is omitted.
```

Until now, in order to solve this problem, I have put a dummy command after 2 and when the debugger lands there, I have see the value of the variable. Is there any better way than this?

### Edit

To make my question clearer, I would say that this example is a little bit tricky. The time series variable is sent to the method and the method should process it and send it back. When the debugger is on 2, the method is not executed. When I continue, it goes directly to the 3 and i cannot see the result of the time series variable because 3 is out of scope of the variable

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question exactly.  When the debugger stops on 3, it's should be before that line is executed so you can see the value of the result of 2 without any modifications.  Also, what debugger are you using?  Most support "watches" which let you write expressions which are evaluated at every break point and display the value there, so you could have a watch for timeSeries and see it at every breakpoint.

Comment: what IDE are you using? With eclipse you can go to 3 and hover your mouse over timeSeries and you will see the current value.

Comment: No, in this example, the time series variable is local variable. When the debugger is on 3, it is out of scope of the time series variable.

Comment: simply add another line after 2 and before the end bracket. Then put a break point on it.

Comment: @Dakoda I have written in my question, that I do already so. I think that should be a better way to handle this. Because when the code is in server, i need to compile the whole code and deploy it. That costs me min 5 minutes.